# doGET in Servlet does not write in the html page

Tags: javascript, html, tomcat, servlets

This is my javascript part

```
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction()   {

                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Test/Servlet");

                request.send();

                //document.write("Request GET enviado!");

            }
</script>
```

This is my doGEt part

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Request GET recebido!");

        // JDBC driver name and database URL
        String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Tests";

        //  Database credentials
        String USER = "fabio";
        String PASS = "hacking";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        // Set response content type
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            // Open a connection
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            // Execute SQL query
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            out.println("<html><body>");
            // Extract data from result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                //Retrieve by column name
                int person_id = rs.getInt("person_id");
                String first_name = rs.getString("first_name");
                String last_name = rs.getString("last_name");

                //Display values
                out.println("Person ID: " + person_id + " | ");
                out.println("First name: " + first_name + " | ");
                out.println("Last name: " + last_name + "<br>");

            }
            out.println("</body></html>");

            // Clean-up environment
            out.close();
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

They work until the point that data is retrieved from DB. The part that does not work is posting the out.println back to HTML page. Could someone please advise?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: It shows nothing on the page. I was expecting it would print a line with the data from DB.

Comment: It's possible that it's throwing an exception which is just closing off the output stream. Can you check the `catalina.out` for stacktraces/errors and post anything relevant?

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious for me from the question if you did anything with the response like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var respdiv = document.getElementById("respdiv");
    respdiv.innerHTML = "Response=" + xhr.responseText;
}
xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/Test/Servlet", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Also it was interesting that running in built in eclipse browser it responded with "hello" instead of "SOMETHING" (did not check why) but worked when opened in chrome.
doGet code:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("SOMETHING");
out.flush();
out.close();
```